# Editing OSM Networks in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, openstreetmap, network-analyst, arcgis-editor-osm

I have a shapefile containing paths that I want to add to the line file prior to creating my OSM network using ArcGIS OSM Editor. How should I do this?